# Show Div with Image Map?

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I have an image that is divided into 10 different polys and need a div to show up when hovered over a poly and then remain up until I move off the image, or for the div to change info if I hover over a different poly.

I was trying to do this via CSS+HTML but can't get it to work the way I want. Maybe I need JQuery or something but don't have a clue what to do with that.

You can see via images what I'm looking to accomplish here http://red.imakethat.com/page-1/ where I have sort of a before and after.

Thanks!

Comment: I think your looking for **[jQuery Tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)**

Comment: @Shivam is right. There are many, many Tooltip plugins.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a:hover on the link itself and change a hidden div from display:hidden to display:block and use positioning on the overlapping piece. But that will only work if you use just the type as the link.

To make an entire poly clickable, you'll have to resort either to using an image map with either the css mentioned above or jquery.

Though you could align a grid of nine boxes and put each poly inside as a background graphic but to allow the proper width and height for each graphic, you'll have some overlap as to where the clickable areas would be.